# Visual Studio 2017 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextBuffer FactoryService but found 0 after applying applicable constraints

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, installation, project

When I new installed Visual Studio 2017, I just cannot new a C++ source file. I looked up on the Internet, somethings happen to Visual Studio 2010, 2012,but those solutions don't solve my problems.

Comment: The installer is very granular and may not have installed the C++ components.  Check the "Individual Components" tab in the installer and add/check you have the required components.

Comment: Hi windyafx, could you please share the detail steps to reproduce your issue? Make sure the workload 'Desktop development with C++' is be installed during the VS 2017 installation. You can re-run the VS 2017 installer and click the icon beside 'Launch', select 'Modify' to confirm it.